# Cant use Bootstrap Toggle within table td?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I generate html table using [bootstraptoggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) as follows.

```
var configTableDiv = document.getElementById('exportListContent');

output = '<tr><td><input id="toggle-mode" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="warning" data-offstyle="info"></td></tr>';

configTableDiv.innerHTML = configTableDiv.innerHTML + output;
```

But relevant functionality or design not working within table `td`. It shows normal check box. Is there any solution?

Here is the relevant html output.

```
<td><input id="toggle-mode" type="checkbox" checked="" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="warning" data-offstyle="info" data-on="Kite" data-off="InAppPurchase"></td>
```

Comment: Please show us your html

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Updated

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `jquery`.

```
var configTableDiv = document.getElementById('exportListContent');
output = '<tr><td><input id="toggle-mode" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="warning" data-offstyle="info"></td></tr>';
configTableDiv.innerHTML = configTableDiv.innerHTML + output;
$('#toggle-mode').bootstrapToggle();
```

```js
var configTableDiv = document.getElementById('exportListContent');
output = '<tr><td><input id="toggle-mode" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="warning" data-offstyle="info"></td></tr>';
configTableDiv.innerHTML = configTableDiv.innerHTML + output;
$('#toggle-mode').bootstrapToggle();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<table id="exportListContent">
</table>
```

Comment: Cant get relevant view of checkbox. It shows normal checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

I think it works fine.

```js
var configTableDiv = document.getElementById('exportListContent');

output = '<tr><td><input id="toggle-mode" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="warning" data-offstyle="info"></td></tr>';

configTableDiv.innerHTML = configTableDiv.innerHTML + output;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<table id="exportListContent"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfect just make sure you include `jquery.js`, `bootstrap-toggle.min.js`, `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap-toggle.min.css`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<td><input id="toggle-mode" type="checkbox" checked="" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="warning" data-offstyle="info" data-on="Kite" data-off="InAppPurchase"></td>
```

Comment: I included those things but not working. I think problem occurs when creating a DOM in JavaScript.